# MS outlook html email breakage

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a fluid html emailer with the following layout.

[image]

It looks cool when tested in browsers and phone browsers but the html breaks when in MS outlook.
Layout in outlook:

[image]

The images in the center are inside a table with "display:inline-block" and the table is center aligned.

Can anyone help me solve this issue with outlook?

PS. The entire emailer in designed using tables only.

Comment: Could we see some code? or a Jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses MS Word to render HTML, which could cause part of the problem.

The other thing to note with emailing HTML is that your styles can't be in classes, but rather need to be inline.

Comment: Yes Charley all my styles are inline and not in classes. I am just facing this issue in outlook and no where else at all. With some R&D if fount that if i left align my tables, outlook displays the stuff well but the emailer dosent look so good in mobile phone browsers. Is there a way through which i can just left align the tables only for outlook and no where else. Conditional css is one way which i am trying now. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net) to show what you have?